# Выделение определенного количества памяти из кучи

Tags: c++, память

Как выделить определенное количество памяти из кучи? Например: мне надо выделить 5 байт памяти из кучи, каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: Цель какая?  Просто так же память не выделяют, а под конкретные данные: `struc5bytes *struc5 = new struc5bytes;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Странный вопрос. Память в куче выделяется для динамических переменных.
>   Например так:
>
> char* array = new char[5];

Не забудьте, что кроме выделения памяти, память надо будет не забыть вернуть в кучу после использования.

```
char* array = new char[5];  //выделение памяти из кучи
delete [] array;            //возврат памяти в кучу
```

UPD1:

Не забудьте, что если Вы получаете не массив, а один элемент, то оператор возврата памяти в кучу имеет другой вид (без квадратных скобок).

```
char* ptr = new char;  //выделение одного элемента 
delete ptr;            //возврат одного элемента в кучу
```

Answer (score 5):

Концептуально с кучей (*heap*) оперируют `malloc` и `free`, а `new/delete` работают с областью памяти, называемой "*free store*". И хотя `new` и `delete` могут быть (скорее всего так и есть в вашем компиляторе) реализованы через `malloc` и `free` соответственно, ответ на ваш вопрос будет такой:

```
void* p = malloc(5); // выделяет память из кучи
```

В то время как вариант с `new` выделит память из *free store*:

```
void* p = new char[5]; // выделяет память из free store
```

Правильнее всё-таки будет использовать вариант с `operator new`, а не выражение с массивом:

```
void* p = ::operator new(5); // всё ещё free store
```

При этом в самом стандарте С++ термин куча (heap) используется исключительно для [структуры данных "куча"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)).

По поводу дополнительных различий *heap* и *free store* можно обратиться к [вопросу на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1350819/3240681).

Answer (score 1):

Странный вопрос. Память в куче выделяется для динамических переменных.
Например так:

```
char* array = new char[5];
```