# Избыточность оператора delete[] в С++

Tags: c++, выделение-памяти

Тут я как всегда не вовремя задумался вот над каким вопросом. При выделении памяти из кучи очевидно, что в куче должна сохраняться информация о размере запрошенной области памяти и о количестве запрошенных элементов. Зачем же тогда существуют отдельно операторы `delete` и `delete[]`? Ведь независимо от того, запросили мы вектор или один элемент, в куче есть информация и о размере запрошенной области, и о количестве запрошенных элементов. Не может быть, чтобы при запросе одного элемента в куче не сохранялась информация о том, что запрошен один элемент. А если это так, то оператор `delete` вполне может разобраться (по служебной информации, содержащейся в куче) был ли запрошен массив или был запрошен один элемент. И, соответственно, вернуть в кучу память или одного элемента, или вектора. Получается, что оператор `delete[]` избыточен.

UPD1:

> В нынешнем подходе С++ поступает более экономично: хранит свою
>   дополнительную информацию только в массивах объектов с нетривиальным
>   деструктором.

То есть Вы хотите сказать, что у кучи есть несколько форматов? Один формат для запрошенного одного элемента, другой формат для запрошенного вектора, третий формат для запрошенного одного элемента с нетривиальным аллокатором/деструктором, четвертый формат для запрошенного вектора с нетривиальным аллокатором/деструктором? Ну, это дело конечно разработчиков компилятора и кучи, как там они видят свою задачу чтобы сделать ее максимально эффективной. Но на первый взгляд иметь много форматов кучи это не так чтобы однозначно было эффективнее, чем хранить всю информацию и в рантайме разбираться, что же именно там сейчас лежит. Тем более, что разбираться в рантайме и при подходе со многими форматами кучи все равно придется.

UPD2:

И да, нетривиальный аллокатор тоже хранит в куче информацию о количестве запрошенных элементов и о размере одного элемента. Имея эту информацию нетривиальный деструктор может разобраться, что именно ему надо удалять. И опять же в этом случае не нужен оператор delete[], достаточно оператора delete.

UPD3:

Оставим пока в покое нетривиальные аллокаторы. Рассмотрим пока что стандартные аллокаторы, тем более что проблемы в обоих случаях одинаковы.

Итак, есть куча и есть операторы new и new[]. Оба оператора обязаны занести в служебную информацию кучи данные о размере одного объекта и о КОЛИЧЕСТВЕ ОБЪЕКТОВ в запросе. Соответственно, оператор возврата памяти delete нужен только один, так как по служебной информации рантайм может и должен разобраться сколько именно объектов было запрошено. Соответственно, оператор delete[] избыточен.

Теперь рассмотрим нестандартные (пользовательские) аллокаторы. Совершенно так же пользовательские new и new[] обязаны занести в служебную информацию кучи данные о размере одного объекта и о КОЛИЧЕСТВЕ ОБЪЕКТОВ в запросе. Дополнительно пользовательские new и new[] обязаны занести в служебную информацию кучи указатель на пользовательский деструктор. Опять же в этом случае оператор возврата памяти delete нужен только один, так как по служебной информации рантайм может и должен разобраться сколько именно объектов было запрошено. Соответственно, оператор delete[] избыточен.

Comment: Вопрос, как я понимаю, не в том, сколько памяти запрошено, а в том, вызывать ли один деструктор или для всех элементов.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/796215/317064

Comment: Да и [не в куче](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/932426/176217), в общем-то.

Comment: Откуда у вас эта упорная фантазия о том, что рантайм хранит размер одного объекта и их количество? При, он может там хранить, например указатель на деструктор для оператора без квадратных скобок. И указатель на деструктор + количество вызовов для []

Comment: @Harry, я бы тоже так ответил_ этого достаточно (я думаю), для существования обеих операторов

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Во-первых, даже если в куче и сохраняется информация о размере запрошенного блока *в байтах*, способ хранения этой информации может быть известен `delete` только в том случае, если используется "штатный" аллокатор. Но процесс выделения "сырой" памяти в С++ является перегружаемым пользователем. Как только выделение памяти перешло на пользовательский аллокатор, `delete` уже не может определить размер блока.

Во-вторых, даже если размер блока *в байтах* известен, по этому размеру все равно нельзя однозначно восстановить точное количество элементов в массиве, чтобы вызвать точное количество деструкторов. Размер блока может превышать точное значение, требуемое для хранения элементов.

В-третьих, не ясно, о каком "количестве запрошенных элементов" вы говорите. Количество запрошенных элементов сохраняет именно `new []` и вычитывает именно `delete []`. Для того, собственно, `delete []` и сделан отдельным от `delete`. Смотрите детали здесь: [Откуда C/C++ знает сколько надо освободить памяти, если не знает размер массива?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/796215/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-c-c-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Теоретически можно сделать "умный `delete`", который сам всегда во всем разбирается. Но это приведет к безусловной необходимости хранить дополнительную информацию во *всех* блоках памяти. В нынешнем подходе С++ поступает более экономично: хранит свою дополнительную информацию только в массивах объектов с нетривиальным деструктором.

Фактически почти такой "умный `delete`" у вас уже есть. Никто вам не запрещает везде просто безусловно пользоваться `new[]/delete[]` и забыть про существование `new/delete`. То есть одиночные объекты просто выделять как массивы размера 1. Но это будет несколько более расточительно (и не поддерживает полиморфного удаления).

---

Отвечая на ваш UPD1:

В типичной реализации у блока в С++ куче фактически **три** формата: для одиночного объекта (`new`), для массива с тривиальными деструкторами (`new[]`) и для массива с нетривиальными деструкторами (`new[]`).

При этом первые два формата можно было бы считать совпадающими с точки зрения внутренней структуры, т.к. это просто "блоки памяти". Но тут вмешивается тот факт, что механизмы выделения/освобождения "сырой" памяти в С++ являются перегружаемыми пользователем: независимо для `new/delete` и для `new[]/delete[]`. Поэтому это - отдельные форматы.

---

Ответ на ваш UPD3:

Я не знаю, с чего вы взяли, что "Оба оператора обязаны занести в служебную информацию кучи данные о размере одного объекта и о КОЛИЧЕСТВЕ ОБЪЕКТОВ в запросе". Это совершенно не так.

Еще раз: просто `new` такой информации НЕ сохраняет. И `new[]` для типов с тривиальным деструктором никакой информации о количестве или размере объектов НЕ хранит тоже. Эти форматы просто выделяют память через обычный `malloc`, освобождают через обычный `free` и никакой дополнительной внутренней информации в этом блоке памяти не сохраняют. С точки зрения С++ памяти требуется ровно столько, сколько нужно для хранения пользовательских данных.

Особняком стоит только `new[]` для массива с нетривиальными деструкторами. Только он сохраняет в блоке служебную информацию о точном количестве элементов в массиве (и поэтому выделяет несколько больше памяти, чем требуется для пользовательских данных).

Информация о размере одного элемента в таком блоке не хранится вообще никогда - это низачем не нужно.

Я при этом говорю только о стандартных аллокаторах. Пользовательские аллокаторы тут ни при чем.

Comment: Ок, я еще подумаю. Почему-то мне вдруг показалось, что невозможно сделать кучу, не сохраняя информацию о количестве запрошенных элементов.

Comment: Я бы добавил абзац на счёт деталей реализации. Это звучит голословно и я не могу сейчас это подтвердить, но, например, в delete[] из msvc знает размер выделенной памяти и количество элементов в нем (Со слов одного уважаемого мною человека).

Comment: @MrBin: Детали реализации приведены в моем ответе по ссылке. И еще раз: "размер выделенной памяти" известен, но интересен только условному `free`, вызываемому из `delete[]`. Самому `delete[]` общий размер выделенной памяти не интересен. Количество элементов `delete[]` знает только в том случае, когда элементы массива имеют *нетривиальный деструктор*. В противном случае количество элементов массива `delete []` не знает (и оно ему не нужно). Так все работает на практике и в MSVC, и в GCC, и еще много где. Скорее всего именно это вам и пытался объяснить "уважаемый вами человек".

Comment: @AnT, да, сам `delete[]` не знает.

Answer (score 10):

Вы смешиваете в одну кучу интерфейс и детали реализации. И, вероятнее всего, забываете, что С++ используется не только на x86-совмесимых системах.

Язык (интерфейс) ничего не знает о куче. Это реализация. New вполне может выделять память, например, из slab-аллокатора, в то время как New[] будет использовать кучу.

К тому же на микроконтроллерах есть серьезное ограничение по памяти, и делать одинаковую реализацию New/Delete и New[]/Delete[] просто расточительно, т.к. вторая пара должна знать не только размер участка памяти, но и количество реальных элементов в нем.

Answer (score 6):

Дело в том что хотя рантайм и знает размер(что в общем случае не верно, он может размер и не хранить), он не знает что там содержится. Теоретически можно попытаться угадать, но тогда алгоритм угадывания придется описать в спецификации. Это ненужное усложнение.

Краткий ответ: чтобы не усложнять спецификацию и оставить ее более гибкой.

Answer (score 6):

Насколько мне известно, существование `new / delete` и `new[] / delete[]` обосновано девизом: `не платим за то, что не используем`.

Такой подход позволяет экономить память и такты на лишних проверках.

Безусловно, менеджер памяти хранит информацию о размере каждого блока, однако одного лишь размера блока памяти недостаточно, чтобы корректно обработать удаление массива объектов, вызвав для каждого объекта его деструктор.

В `C` такой проблемы разделения нет, потому что `free()` просто освобождает память, не вызывая деструкторы.

Если же мы попытаемся удалить массив объектов `C++`, используя только информацию о размере блока памяти, то мы не сможем этого сделать. Нам не хватает информации.

Поэтому, `new[]` заводит для каждого массива объектов минимум два счетчика. Содержимое этих счетчиков зависит от реализации компилятора, но обычно в счетчиках хранятся `размер блока памяти` и `тип объекта`. Зная тип объекта - мы имеем информацию о размере объекта и его деструкторе.

Только в этом случае информации становится достаточно, чтобы корректно вызвать деструктор для каждого объекта массива, а затем освободить блок памяти.

Если бы существовал только `delete`, который умел бы работать и с одиночными объектами, и с массивами объектов, тогда при работе с одиночными объектами происходил бы перерасход памяти и тактов процессора на лишние проверки.

Подтверждением этой *теории* служит тот факт, что следующий код:

```
while (1)
{
    float *arr = new float[1000];
    delete arr;

    arr = new float;
    delete[] arr;
}
```

В большинстве ситуацией не приводит к падениям или утечкам. Да, это `UB`, но я видел множество случаев такого кода, который был написан умышленно и работал годами.

Поскольку `float` не имеет деструктора, то и проблем при *перепутывании* `delete` и `delete[]` чаще всего не возникает.

Конечно, внутри все это устроено намного сложнее, но общая суть происходящего примерно такая.

Comment: `не платим за то, что не используем` - внезапно `new []` / `delete []` как раз прямо нарушают этот принцип, так как рантайм совершенно без участия пользователя будет также хранить размер выделенного массива приводя к неустранимому оверхеду. *"был написан умышленно"* - это называется вредительство, *"работал годами"* - этот код не работает