# Динамическое vs Статическое выделение памяти

Tags: c++, c, память

Есть структура:

```
typedef struct Point
{
   int x;
   int y;
} point_t;
```

Каким способом лучше создать "экземпляр" структуры?

1. способ:

   ```
    point_t p;
   ```
2. способ:

   ```
    point_t* p = new point_t();
   ```

1 способ предпочтительнее из-за скорости, но не редко я вижу 2 способ. Так в чем же разница (кроме возможности сделать `delete` когда захочется)?

Comment: Зависит от того, что вам нужно. Вопрос из серии на чем лучше ездить - на грузовике или на автобусе? исходите из конкретной задачи...

Comment: Ну динамическое выделение памяти имеет место быть, когда вам заранее неизвестно сколько чего будет. Например, вы парсите xml документ и выделяете память под ноды.

Comment: @Harry Как раз я не понимаю на чем мне лучше ездить. Можете сказать куда копать? Может какие-то ссылки есть?

Comment: @GetName Вы так говорите, как-будто Вам обязательно нужно выбрать один какой-то способ, и использовать только его, так как он "лучше". Если бы это было так, то был бы только один способ, "лучший", а худшего в принципе бы не было в языке, а зачем. Но в C++ два способа, следовательно есть ситуации когда удобнее один, а есть ситуации, когда удобнее другой. `std::lock_guard` - это один из примеров использования плюсов хранения объектов на стеке. Пример использования плюсов динамического хранения объектов - `std::list`, который внутри использует динамич. выделение памяти для работы с узлами списка.

Comment: статическое используется, чтобы автоматически удалился объект из стека. А динамическое - нет. Вот и вся разница.

Comment: по моему правильный ответ на этот вопрос в данном контексте такой: "если нет причин выделять динамически, всегда выделяй статически" (как бы разновидность принципа KISS)

Comment: Во-первых, не "динамичное и статичное", а динамическое и статическое. Во-вторых, термин *статический* не является и никогда не являлся антонимом к термину *динамический*. Про локальные переменные не говорят, что они "выделены статически".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разница в способе хранения данных.

---

В первом случае переменные хранятся в **стеке** программы. Из этого следует:

1. Ограниченные область видимости и время жизни.
2. При выходе из области видимости происходит автоматическое разрушение хранимых переменных.
3. Более высокая скорость выделения/освобождения памяти.

---

Во втором случае хранение переменных происходит в **куче**. Куча медленнее стека выделяет и освобождает ресурсы, автоматически не очищается (по крайней мере в стандартном C++), подвержена фрагментации. Однако имеет некоторые особенности:

1. Время жизни переменной не ограничено процессом выполнения. Без явного вызова `delete` переменная будет существовать до конца выполнения программы.
2. Зная адрес переменной в куче, к ней можно получить доступ из любой области видимости.
3. Куча в некотором смысле "резиновая". В отличие от стека, она ограничена только физически.

---

В итоге, создание в стеке следует использовать в случаях, когда переменная небольшого или приемлемого размера либо используется только здесь и нигде больше.

Если же переменная должна использоваться в процессе жизни всей программы, доступ к ней нужен в любой момент времени, ее создание/копирование занимает много времени/памяти или же неизвестно заранее, какой объем памяти нужен, то есть смысл использовать кучу (создать один раз и потом использовать готовый экземпляр из кучи, нежели создавать и инициализировать каждый раз аналог в стеке).

Однако, при работе с кучей нужно быть осторожным. Ошибки при работе с динамической памятью чреваты утечками памяти и sigsegv-ами.

Советую еще почитать про [представление кучи и стека](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/277295/192978). Там есть ссылки на полезную информацию.

**UPD**: Касательно скорости работы с кучей привожу выхлоп дизассемблера Qt 5.13 (MinGW 7.3.0):

```
        3 [1]   {
0x401560                  55                    push   %rbp
0x401561  <+    1>        48 89 e5              mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x401564  <+    4>        48 83 ec 30           sub    $0x30,%rsp
0x401568  <+    8>        e8 f3 00 00 00        callq  0x401660 <__main>
        4 [1]       int a = 10;
0x40156d  <+   13>        c7 45 fc 0a 00 00 00  movl   $0xa,-0x4(%rbp)
        6 [1]       int *b = new int{10};
0x401574  <+   20>        b9 04 00 00 00        mov    $0x4,%ecx
0x401579  <+   25>        e8 22 00 00 00        callq  0x4015a0 <_Znwy>
0x40157e  <+   30>        c7 00 0a 00 00 00     movl   $0xa,(%rax)
0x401584  <+   36>        48 89 45 f0           mov    %rax,-0x10(%rbp)
        7 [1]       delete b;
0x401588  <+   40>        48 8b 45 f0           mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
0x40158c  <+   44>        48 89 c1              mov    %rax,%rcx
0x40158f  <+   47>        e8 14 00 00 00        callq  0x4015a8 <_ZdlPv>
        9 [1]       return 1;
0x401594  <+   52>        b8 01 00 00 00        mov    $0x1,%eax
        10 [1]  }
0x401599  <+   57>        48 83 c4 30           add    $0x30,%rsp
0x40159d  <+   61>        5d                    pop    %rbp
0x40159e  <+   62>        c3                    retq
```

Видно, что при работе с динамической памятью присутствуют дополнительные инструкции плюс вызов процедуры. Плюс к куче в многопоточных приложениях добавляются вопросы синхронизации (это конечно достаточно вторичный момент, но он тоже имеет место быть)

P.S. если что-то забыл, буду благодарен за дополнения.

Comment: > Более высокая скорость доступа.<
Много кто это говорит, но никто не подтверждает. Откуда такая информация? С более высокой скоростью единичного выделения согласен, у кучи O(logn), у стека O(1), а доступ? Если опустить потенциальные особенности реализации виртуальной адресации, то разве не одинаковая скорость доступа оказывается? PS. Кроме того, при работе на нормальном компьютере врятли эта разница окажется узким местом...

Comment: `Куча медленнее стека` - это ещё что за новость?

Comment: @zcorvid Если опустить то да, но на практике на нормальных камнях стек прогретый в кэше лежит. На ненормальных камнях там что угодно может быть.

Comment: @zcorvid, со скоростью доступа оговорился. Я хотел сказать скорость работы.

Comment: @PavelGridin, я имел ввиду куча медленнее в плане выделения/освобождения памяти. Обновил ответ и привел пример дизассемблера.

Comment: еще бы кто объяснил в чем разница между стэком и кучей)))

Comment: "Куча в некотором смысле "резиновая". Может расширяться до тех пор, пока не кончится RAM."? Никакого отношения к "RAM" в современных ОС с виртуальной памятью предельный размер кучи уже давно не имеет.

Comment: @Bogdan, тогда понятно

Comment: [Небольшое терминологическое замечание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/932426/176217): с "кучей" оперируют `free/malloc`, а `new/delete` работают с "free store".

Comment: Если нужны преимущества динамического выделения памяти, но еще необходима и скорость, то в C++ можно переопределить операторы new и delete, так чтобы использовался свой, более быстрый чем куча аллокатор, например SLAB.