# Где правильно создавать объекты в куче или стеке?

Tags: c++, ооп

Мне нужно создать два класса с простым интерфейсом. Один класс содержит контейнер вектор с объектами другого класса.

У первого класса реализованы методы сеттеры и геттеры. А у второго соответственно поиск нужного объекта в контейнере и подобный интерфейс. Склоняюсь к созданию объектов на стеке, т.к. никаких манипуляций с указателями не совершаю, к тому же их жизнь ограничена только функцией main().

Верно ли я рассуждаю? Или все-таки стоит всегда создавать объекты на куче?

Comment: Ничего плохого в том, чтобы создавать объекты на стеке, нету.

Comment: *Чем правильно есть - ложкой или вилкой?* Вы удивитесь - что за бред? зависит от того, что есть - суп или бифштекс, грубо говоря... Вот так и - где создавать объекты - зависит от того, для чего, какая у них должна быть продолжительность жизни, etc etc... Нет единого универсального решения!

Comment: Размер стека ограничен. Если всё влезает в него - хорошо. Не влезает - добро пожаловать в кучу. Хотя можно подумать о пулах объектов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Склоняюсь к созданию объектов на стеке, т.к. никаких манипуляций с указателями не совершаю, к тому же их жизнь ограничена только функцией main().

1. Жизнь объекта в функции `main()` по сути равна жизни во время выполнения всей программы. Поэтому касательно времени жизни в этом случае разницы между стеком и кучей нет никакой, если, конечно, в середине `main` явно не прописан `delete` (что маловероятно и достаточно бессмысленно).
2. "Манипуляции с указателями" - это скорее следствие использования кучи, нежели критерий выбора того, как создавать объекты.

> Верно ли я рассуждаю? Или все-таки стоит всегда создавать объекты на куче?

Все программирование в целом это такая вещь, которая предлагает целый набор совершенно разных способов решить одну и ту же задачу. Среди них нет единственно лучшего и правильного, который *стоит использовать всегда*. Каждый имеет свои особенности. Чтобы выбрать, какой лучше подходит, нужно вникнуть в эти особенности.

---

Правильно создавать и там, и там (или вернее уметь создавать). Зависит от конкретной задачи.

Если же описанный *другой класс* (элемент контейнера) сам по себе маленький по размеру, то при создании объектов в стеке проблем, как правило, никаких не должно быть. Если же размер объекта более существенный, то есть вероятность переполнить стек.

Более подробно об отличиях стека и кучи можно почитать в [похожем топике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1020310/192978).

Answer (score -2):

Везде где можно использовать стек нужно использовать стек.
Потому что:

1. Стек быстрее нежели куча (Обрабатывается ЦП)
2. Память освобождается автоматически при выходе из скопа и как следствие меньше проблем с утечкой памяти.

Так что рассуждение верно.

Comment: >Стек быстрее нежели куча< И в чём же конкретно он быстрее? Уже много раз это обсуждалось, и всегда в итоге сходились на том, что доступ что по стеку, что по куче одинаков по скорости. Быстрее лишь выделение/очистка памяти (у стека константа, у кучи логарифм).

Comment: [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1020273/%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-vs-%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8/1020310#1020310) в комментариях есть обсуждение.